# MySQL - SSL is required but the server doesn't support it

Tags: mysql, ssl, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to enable SSL in MySQL. I ran the SSL Wizard on MySQL Workbench which generated these files:

- `ca-cert.pem`
- `ca-key.pem`
- `client-cert.pem`
- `client-key.pem`
- `server-cert.pem`
- `server-key.pem`

Then I changed `my.cnf` file like this:

```
[client]
ssl-ca=<directory>/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=<directory>/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=<directory>/client-key.pem

[mysqld]
ssl-ca=<directory>/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=<directory>/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=<directory>/server-key.pem
```

where `<directory>` is the directory where these files are located.

Then I set the configuration file path in MySQL Workbench and restarted mysql service but when I test the connection it gives me this error:

> ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL is required but the
>   server doesn't support it

How can I solve this?

Comment: What OS is the MySQL service running on?

Comment: @DaveS Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: WOrkbench sits in the same machine as MYSQL server?

Comment: @Alfabravo Yes it's all in localhost

Comment: Restarted the mysql-server service after changing configuration?

Comment: @Alfabravo Yes, I wrote it in the question

Comment: Can I connect without SSL? HeidiSQL is able to make it, but MySQL WB couldn't :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it was solved by changing the certificate files permission.

```
sudo chmod 444 ca-cert.pem;
sudo chmod 444 client-cert.pem;
sudo chmod 400 client-key.pem;

sudo chmod 444 ca-cert.pem;
sudo chmod 444 server-cert.pem;
sudo chmod 400 server-key.pem;

sudo chown mysql:mysql ca-cert.pem;
sudo chown mysql:mysql client-cert.pem;
sudo chown mysql:mysql client-key.pem;

sudo chown mysql:mysql ca-cert.pem;
sudo chown mysql:mysql server-cert.pem;
sudo chown mysql:mysql server-key.pem;
```

Restart the server...

Comment: I've changed the ownership and permissions of `.pem` files and moved the client `.pem` files in a directory and the server `.pem` in another; it works but only if I use the mysql client with `sudo`, maybe because the client files are owned by mysql user. Is there a way to connect without `sudo`?

Comment: I do connect without ```sudo```, I think this is possible because the certificate files are owned by ```mysql``` user.

Comment: final sentence is important "Restart the server..."

Comment: I cannot believe that file ownership has such a huge role in this...

Answer (score 0):

Change these 2 lines :

```
ssl-cert=<directory>//server-cert.pem
ssl-key=<directory>//server-key.pem
```

I had same problem,searched a lot and then I found, the thing is that MYSQL server interprets "/s" as "space".

So /server for server means /erver something.

Comment: I've changed these lines but it always gives me the error

Comment: can you post <directory>?

Comment: I've followed this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-ssl-wizard.html

Comment: @Demetrio Odd because the suggestion done in the answer is actually in the document you link to and the conf data you provided did not. Did you see the message stated in step 6?

Comment: @Alfabravo No it didn't appear

Comment: Then it is not properly configured.